# How to detect value change in from uri in Apache camel blueprint

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I am struck with one thing..I want to check whether value from "from uri" of apache camel blueprint is changed wrt to previous value or not everytime when route is called.

For example :-

```
<route>
  <from uri="ftp://foo@myserver?password=secret&amp;
           recursive=true&amp;ftpClient.dataTimeout=30000&amp;
           ftpClientConfig.serverLanguageCode=fr"/>
  <to uri="bean:doSomething"/>
</route>
```

in above example every time when from uri is called i want to check whether the output from URI is different from previous output in blueprint only.

I have achieved this through Java code,But i want to achieve it through blueprint SPRING DSL only.Does anyone have idea about this???

Comment: What do you mean? The FTP is for downloading files from a FTP server. Do you talk about idempotent consumer? http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html

Comment: @Claus lbsen : That was an example what I mean is for example I get an string from uri like name is Malatesh and next time if I get new string as claus I should know that the value from uri is changed in blueprint that way..

Comment: The output from "from ftp" is the file that was downloaded from the FTP server. There are headers on the Camel message that tells you the file name, file size etc. The key are Exchange.FILE_NAME etc. So you can use that to "know if it was a different file".

Comment: @ClausIbsen: Thank you..I would look into it,Actually the output we are getting is and object for example kind of string object,I tried using exchangeproperty to set but i found some exceptions like this is supported... in blueprint...